# What gauge is the super thin wire in headset cable (e.g smartphone)

Tags: wire

What is the gauge of the thin wires in a headset? I can tell they are stranded (not solid) and coated with paint as insulation. They appear to be finer than the 24 AWG that is in an Ethernet cable.

I need to repair a micro drone and want to use super fine wire. I found some hookup wire at a store that is 26 or 28 AWG but it has super thick insulation which kind of defeats the point.

Comment: Look for some enameled magnet wire, AWG 32 to 38.  You can probably find some off of small inductors.  Typically, you can solder right through the enamel, but you might have to strip it a bit with some fine sandpaper.

Comment: It is probably [Litz wire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Litz_wire). In a headset it may be used just as much for its flexibility as for reducing the skin effect.

Answer (score 1):

This sort of wire is sometimes known as 'Magnet Wire' or similar names because it is frequently used for making inductors or motor coils. You can generally find it in many different wire gauges, usually coated with either enamel or polyurethane insulation.

[This is one example](http://uk.farnell.com/5017233) that I have used before. It's 38AWG coated wire which is quite easy to remove the coating from with heat (you can also get it in different colours). There are many other options around.

You have to be careful though to check the current spec for this sort of wire. Given how small the diameter is, they are only usually rated for ~100mA or so at the most for the narrowest wire. Just make sure you're not going to be drawing more than its rated current to avoid heating (which could destroy the insulation if too extreme) or melting.

Comment: thanks both. i will check out this magnet wire...but i do see that the existing wire on the microdrone appears to be typical multistrand (flexible) wire with a flexible plastic insulation. it is just very thin. do you know if this is avail online. i couldnt find thin stranded gauge and thin insulation